# Is there a Webpack plugin that generates sprites for CSS?

Tags: webpack

I want to find webpack css sprites plugin that allows me to define list of images that I want to use in sprites image and reference these images in a common way.

I.e. in my css I will write something like this:

```
some-selector-a {
    ...
    background-image: url('images/home.png');
    ...
}

some-selector-b {
    ...
    background-image: url('images/mail.png');
    ...
}
```

Plugin should build sprites image from referenced images and perform corresponding css modifications:

```
some-selector-a {
    ...
    background-image: url('sprites.png');
    background-position: -16px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    ...       
}

some-selector-b {
    ...
    background-image: url('sprites.png');
    background-position: -32px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    ...       
}
```

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/glebmachine/postcss-easysprites and https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader

Comment: It looks like it is exactly what I need - simple and effective. Please, add your comment as answer - I will be happy to check it as correct one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with `postcss` and `easysprites` plugins (or any other similar e.g. [postcss-sprites](https://github.com/2createStudio/postcss-sprites)).

You need to add [postcss-loader](http://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader) in your webpack config for css files ([docs](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#usage)) and [enable plugin](https://github.com/glebmachine/postcss-easysprites#usage-1) in `postcss` section:

```
var easysprite = require('easysprite');
...
postcss: function () {
   return [easysprite];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Short answer is no -- based on my experience looking for the same thing. There's a webpack plugin (I think it's a plugin, it may have been a loader) that sprites all the files in a directory, but that's not really what you want with webpack -- a good solution will automatically sprite your image references as they're loaded, and modify your CSS source appropriately.

Good news is I wrote a loader that does this. Bad news is it's not public yet -- hoping I'll be able to open source it soon.